# PHP - Multidimensional Array check for duplicates (without array_unique)

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array, duplicates

**UPDATE**

> I found an answer to this question for myself and I posted it, but i can only accept it in two days..

---

I create this multidimensional array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'OrderDate' => '02.11.2018',
    'ClientNumber' => 5500
  )
)

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'OrderDate' => '02.11.2018',
    'ClientNumber' => 5500
  )
)

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'OrderDate' => '05.03.2018',
    'ClientNumber' => 5500
  )
)

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'OrderDate' => '10.12.2018',
    'ClientNumber' => 2200
  )
)

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'OrderDate' => '10.12.2018',
    'ClientNumber' => 2200
  )
)
```

The array shouldn't contain duplicate OrderDate's from each ClientNumber.

I want the output to look like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'OrderDate' => '02.11.2018',
    'ClientNumber' => 5500
  )
)

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'OrderDate' => '05.03.2018',
    'ClientNumber' => 5500
  )
)

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'OrderDate' => '10.12.2018',
    'ClientNumber' => 2200
  )
)
```

What if-condition should i use to make my output look like this? Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

This is my function that is called in a foreach. I tried my best to check with in_array and array_column but the output didn't look like the code above.

```
$array = array();
function createArray($clientNr, $orderDate){
 if(empty($array)){ // if array is empty, just add
  $array[] = array(
              "OrderDate"=>$orderDate,
              "ClientNumber"=>$clientNr
                 );
 } else {
    if(??????)<--------------------------- // check here if date from clientnumber exists
      $array[] = array(
                   "OrderDate"=>$orderDate,
                   "ClientNumber"=>$clientNr
                  );
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :-

```
$data=array();

$data[0]['OrderDate']='02.11.2018';
$data[0]['ClientNumber']='5500';

$data[1]['OrderDate']='02.11.2018';
$data[1]['ClientNumber']='5500';

$new_arr = array_unique($data, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: But other clientNumbers can have the same OrderDate too

Comment: if client number are different then record will not remove from array. if client number and date are same then array value will be unique please check my eg.

Comment: @ashishkumar Provide explanation of your answer. It'll be helpful to OP

Comment: yash sir if run above example then you can get only one value in array. but if you change orderdate or client number then you can get two records

Comment: Didn't work for me :/

Comment: its woroking for me. please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with below, you can use array_map or array_unique() function

```
$array = array(
  array(
     'OrderDate' => '02.11.2018',
     'ClientNumber' => 5500
  ),
  array(
    'OrderDate' => '02.11.2018',
    'ClientNumber' => 5500
  ),
  array(
    'OrderDate' => '05.03.2018',
    'ClientNumber' => 5500
  ),
  array(
    'OrderDate' => '10.12.2018',
    'ClientNumber' => 2200
  ),
  array(
    'OrderDate' => '10.12.2018',
    'ClientNumber' => 2200
  )
);

$newArr = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));

print_r($newArr);

$newArr1 = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);

print_r($newArr1);
```

Comment: Didn't work for me :/

Answer (score 0):

I did it! Thanks for your approaches, but 
these two didn't work for me:

```
array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
```

This is my solution, I added a unique key and checked, if the key already exists.

```
$id = date("Ymd", strtotime($orderDate)).$clientNr; // creates unique key

if(!array_key_exists($id, $array)){ // check if this key exists and add if not

 $array[$id] = array(
              "OrderDate"=>$orderDate,
              "ClientNumber"=>$clientNr
             );
}
```